# How to copy a NSURL object to an array of CFURL structs

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have an `ivar` that is a 'plain' C array of `CFURLRef` structs. I call this `sourceURLArray`. I initialize it to hold six elements.

Later on, in a function, I create (alloc/init) an `NSURL*` object. I call it `fileURL` and I want to save a copy of that object into the first element of the aforementioned array. I thought all I needed to do was this:

```
        sourceURLArray[0] = (__bridge CFURLRef)([fileURL copy]);
```

However when I execute the code I get **message sent to deallocated instance** messages the second time through the function. Upon inspection of the variables, after the line above executes, `sourceURLArray[0]` holds the same address as `fileURL`. Since `fileURL` goes out of scope when the function completes the address in `sourceURLArray[0]` is deallocated.

It seems I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about either copying, nuances with toll-free bridging, or both.

Comment: Could you provide more code? Where exactly (on which line) application fails? Do you have any global/static variables involved? I'm not sure that failure is related to the line you show

Comment: Alternatively, make the ivar a C array of `NSURL*` and ARC should do the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but I have other functions already written that are expecting CFURLRefs out of this same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sourceURLArray[0] = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)([fileURL copy]);
```

or:

```
sourceURLArray[0] = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([fileURL copy]);
```

This tells ARC that you are transferring ownership to the other array. You must now properly call CFRelease on the `CFURLRef` at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! When I try that the compiler complains that **Cast of Obj-C pointer type id to C pointer type 'CFURLRef' cannot use __bridge_transfer**. It suggests using CFBridgingRetain instead, which worked! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: __bridge_retained equals to CFBridgingRetain, which is correct in rmaddy's answer. You just have a typo in your code with "__bridge_transfer" which equals to CFBridgingRelease.